# How to open Firefox 53 on Robot Framework

Tags: firefox, robotframework, geckodriver

I'm trying to open Firefox 53 using Robot framework (Ride.py). Unfortunately, It gives me the following error

> Demo
>
> ===========================================================================================================
>
> Sample Test
>   | FAIL | SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
>
> ---
>
> Demo
>   | FAIL | 1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed 1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed
>
> ===========================================================================================================

My Robot script looks like this

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Selenium2Library

*** Test Case ***
Sample Test
    Open Browser
    Check Title
    [Teardown]    Close Browser

*** Keywords ***
Open Browser
    open browser    https://google.lk    Firefox
    Maximize Browser Window

Check Title
    Title Should Be    Google`
```

Can someone give me an answer? It's working with the chrome driver ( I have added the geckodriver at the same location.

Comment: The version of the geckodriver is compatible with you Firefox version?

Comment: Yes, It is. I've been using the geckodriver for the TestNG scripts. I used the same one here. Do we have to set system properties?

Comment: Have you tried with all lowercase `firefox`, as described in the [documentation](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Open%20Browser)

Comment: I need to try that. Will try it

Comment: it's not working with gekodriver for some reason but chrome driver is working smoothly

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue with a later version and here is what worked for me.
Please test these and let me know if it solves your issue or we need to look further.

There are two likely solution steps.

1. You are probably using the wrong gecko driver for your FF version. I cannot downgrade my FF to your version, but for v71 where I am at, but I definitely had to get the latest driver for it from:
   https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.26.0

   - Replace your existing driver in c:\bin (or wherever you store them) with this new one.
2. Also, it says you need the MS Visual Studio runtime from:
   https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
   Open Other Tools and Frameworks and choose your flavour for Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2019 (x64 for my notebook)

   - Run the Runtime binary and restart your computer.

Let me know if it worked. If it fails, please add more info why.